# How to properly check for Boolean value in Spring EL expression?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I'm a bit new to using Spring Expression Language but I'm trying to see what is the best way to check a that a Boolean value is not null and true?

For type "Display" there is a property "removeMessage" which is of type `java.lang.Boolean`.
So I want to first check that this value is not null and that it is true. Based on if this is true or not I will either return an empty string or a calculatedMessage.

I am currently checking with below expression:

```
display?.removeMessage != null && display?.removeMessage ? '' : display.calculatedMessage
```

While this works, I was hoping to find a more nicer way to do the null and true check. I was thinking/hoping for something more like how we would check normally such as e.g. *BoolenUtils.isTrue(value)* (apache), or even just checking like *Boolean.TRUE.equals(value)* which takes care of the null check.

Answer (score 0):

Just having this should work , and already include your null check:

```
display?.removeMessage ? null : display.calculatedMessage
```